# Converting Discharge Voltage to Temperature? Hall Effect Thruster Calculation

Tags: propulsion, physics, ion-thruster, plasma

Trying to follow a Hall Effect Thruster design process given in this video:
[Hall Effect Thruster Design Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzhfswCPa6I)

In 25:59, there's a calculation in which the presenter takes discharge voltage and converts it to temperature. Once he gets temperature in Kelvin I see how he gets the temperature in electron Volts, but I don't see how he derives the temperature given discharge voltage.  He says something about atom temperature, but that's all I can pick up from it.

Comment: This video is not meant to be a tutorial; it's a student presenting to a professor. I only watched for about five minutes, but the student does not really explain this at all, and doesn't seem to even answer the professor's questions when asked about this.